# Proving if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

My title pretty much sums up my question. I understand the proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, you use the definition of the derivative and doing some algebra to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \big(f(x) -f(a)\big) = 0$ and thus that shows the continuity.

However, not $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ are functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^1$ and I'm not so sure the same tricks can apply as with a simple $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm a little stumped here, but maybe I'm over thinking it and the algebra didn't get any more difficult. I guess I'm just a little confused what to do with $\big(f(x) - f(a)\big) / (x-a)$ where $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but $x-a$ is in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Answer (score 0):

The same trick works. If $\mathbf{r}(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector valued function, then its derivative is defined exactly as you expect:

$$\mathbf{r}^{\prime}(t) =\lim_{x \rightarrow t} \frac{\mathbf{r}(x)-\mathbf{r}(t)}{x-t}.$$